# LiveScript for loop not behaving or I have the wrong syntax

Tags: javascript, livescript

Under normal circumstances (vanilla JS) I might do something like this -

```
var mystring = "foo";
for(i = 0; i < mystring.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Which will return `[0,1,2`]`

I cannot find the syntax to produce that behavior in LiveScript. The closest I have come is this -

```
 mystring = \foo
 for i from 0 to my.length-1 // note the -1
     console.log i
```

which compiles to this JavaScript -

```
var mystring, i$, to$, i;
mystring = 'foo';
for (i$ = 0, to$ = mystring.length - 1; i$ <= to$; ++i$) {
  i = i$;
  console.log(i);
}
```

This also returns `[0,1,2]`.

If I do not include the `-1` the array returned is `[0,1,2,3]` which is expected because of how LiveScript compiles to JavaScript in this case.

Is it not possible to get a pure 'less than' condition in LiveScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `til`, not `to`

```
for i from 0 til my.length
```

[LiveScript loops](http://livescript.net/#loops)

Comment: *smacks forehead* I have been looking at that section of the docs all morning and somehow - perhaps due to tunnel vision - did not see it.